# How do I tell UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userid); to include a relation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I added a new property and its corresponding table to my database using ASP.NET Identity with Code First like so:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
 {
    ....

    public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }       
 }


public class File
{    
  ..
  public virtual ApplicationUser UserManager { get; set; }

}
```

Now, from some action, when I call:

```
  var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userid);
```

it does get the user with the correct `userid`

I want to `Include` method in Entity Framework to include the navigational property or relation named File (of type File) on the `ApplicationUser` class.

How do I do that with `ASP.NET Identity'`s `UserManager`? I suspect the only way would be to override this method in my custom `UserManager` derived class and do it myself?

I'm trying replace code

`var user = await UserManager.Include(u => u.Files).FindByIdAsync(userid);`

Comment: Has LazyLoading been disabled in your context? If not then this should work.  User.Files should trigger a load of the associated files because the navigation property is virtual.

Comment: How to enable it ? actually this context created using ADO.NET entity model

Comment: is it LazyLoading applicable to ADO.NET entity model's context  ?

Comment: It should be enabled by default.  But not sure about ADO.NET but I imagine if you can set the property 'Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;' on your context it should work. http://www.ryadel.com/en/enable-or-disable-lazyloading-in-entity-framework/

Comment: @PeteG thanks for ur help I added like this `public ProjectEntities(): base("name=ProjectEntities") {this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;}` but same result , its not popping

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include property on ASP.Net Identity 2.0 UserManager.Users.ToListAsync and UserManager.FindByIdAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039407/include-property-on-asp-net-identity-2-0-usermanager-users-tolistasync-and-userm)