# LazyLoading applicable to context that generated through ADO.NET entity model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I just want to know `LazyLoading` applicable to context that generated through ADO.NET entity model's ?

this `ProjectEntities` generated through ADO.NET entity model

to enable `LazyLoading` I added like this

```
public ProjectEntities(): base("name=ProjectEntities") 
{
   this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
}
```

but seems like not working

Comment: Are the properties you are trying to lazy load virtual?

Comment: how do you know that it doesn't work?

Comment: @MarcinIwanowski once I try to use `Include` method in Entity Framework to include the navigational property or relation named File (of type File) on the `ApplicationUser` class , then I'm getting errors

Comment: @Mant101 yes they are more details you can see on this question , this is my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34941521/how-do-i-tell-usermanager-findbyidasyncuserid-to-include-a-relation?noredirect=1#comment57616716_34941521

Comment: That's a little confusing, Include is eager loading, it loads the data up when the query runs. Lazy loading loads the data up on demand and doesn't use Include.

Comment: Could you show much more code and explain what exactly do you want to achieve and what doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

All properties in your entities that reference to other entities should be virtual.

Comment: please look at this question, its my previous one, So I set up all the entities as `virtual` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34941521/how-do-i-tell-usermanager-findbyidasyncuserid-to-include-a-relation?noredirect=1#comment57616716_34941521