# ASP.NET add list to ApplicationUser

Tags: c#, asp.net, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I want to add a list of `MyActivity` object to the standard `ApplicationUser` object created in a `ASP.NET webforms` app:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<MyActivity> Activities { get; set; } // Added that

    public ClaimsIdentity GenerateUserIdentity(ApplicationUserManager manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(GenerateUserIdentity(manager));
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

I defined the MyActivity class as:

```
public class MyActivity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public string SomeProp { get; set; }
}
```

Then I executed "add-migration UserActivities", and "update-database". I have a MyActivities table created, with a User_Id foreign key, referencing AspNetUsers.Id.
All fine.

But now, when I try to add an activity:

```
using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    currentUser.Activities.Add(new MyActivity { SomeProp = "1" });
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I get a `NullReferenceException` (`currentUser.Activities` is null).

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

FindById won't return your custom child collection by default. You can access the Users table directly:

```
var currentUser = db.Users.Include(u => u.Activities).First(u => u.Id == manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

A better way would be to implement your own UserStore that overrides FindById similar to this: [Custom entities with asp net identity (one-to-many)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646939/custom-entities-with-asp-net-identity-one-to-many)