# MVC5 Identity EF 6 Fluid API errors

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm using MVC5, with the default template and identity 2.0 user system with EF6.

I added `OnModelCreating`, to my `ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` class, in order to use the fluid API to create a many-many relationship between two classes.

This caused these errors to come up when I ran `update-database`, even though I did not make any chages to these tables:

> EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>    EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
>   IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.

Searching the internet, I found on another stackoverflow question to add this to my OnModel Creating:

> ```
>       modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
>         modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
>         modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
> ```

This solved those errors, but now I have this error:

> Cannot find the object "dbo.AspNetUserClaims" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

How do I fix this last error, and why do I have all of these errors to fix once I introduce OnModelCreating()?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asp.net Identity Validation Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994590/asp-net-identity-validation-error)

Comment: I think the best solution is just to call base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); from your OnModelCreating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling the base class OnModelCreating, at the end of my overridden one, fixes the problem:

```
base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```

Credit to @Augusto Barreto in comments.

Comment: I was hopeful, because - using MVC5 - I had the exact same error as @Kyle after doing the same fixes (3x). But for me adding the call to `base` I still got the exact same error :S.