# ASP.NET MVC Identity Foreign Key to User

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have read all at stackoverflow but cannot manage my error:

```
 public class Album
  {
    public int AlbumId { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
  }

  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
    public virtual ICollection<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ApplicationDbContext>());
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

And got:

One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

```
photoManager.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
photoManager.Models.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
```

I am stuck!!!
So Please HELP. What is wrong?

Comment: Can you please share the definition of photoManager.Models.IdentityUserLogin and photoManager.Models.IdentityUserRole?

Comment: Seems like ASP.NET MVC Identity is not able to identify the Primary Key(Id) of IdentityUserLogins & IdentityUserRoles Tables. I don't know but may be in SimpleMembershipInitializer 'WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true)' changing your params can help.

Comment: IdentityUserLogin and IdentityUserRole are the default Identity Models - I do not want define my own - at least now. And I do not know why it looks for "photoManager.Models.IdentityUserLogin" reference. It is  the outbox MVC solution - I just added my Album table and try to add ApplicationUser field

Answer (score 0):

Two things need attention

1. Check the DbContext you are using. It may be the case that you can have more than one context and you're using a context which has not been initialized properly
2. Try updating the OnModelCreating:

   ```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
       modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
       modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
   }
   ```

You can refer to the following if you have not already

1.[Modify DbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531201/entitytype-identityuserlogin-has-no-key-defined-define-the-key-for-this-entit)

2.[Change ModelBinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994590/asp-net-identity-validation-error)

3.[Change ModelBinding(Tricky)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913447/user-in-entity-type-mvc5-ef6)

Comment: 1. I use IdentityDbContext  2.  I have protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    } - it means that all is defined in IdentityDbContext

Comment: Thank you all guys. I checked my code twice  and found a GHOST old Dbcontext that I used before I merged it with ApplicationDbContext. And some classes used it. My stupid mistake!!!

Comment: Please provide detailed answer, this is something what im struggling too

Comment: Told you that their must be some issue with your DbContext. :)

Comment: JON >> search your code for other "old" DbContext  - and remove or at least comment that. And you will see does any class use that old DbContext or not.