# ASP.NET MVC connect existing UserId from UserAuthentication with own Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

I've searched to a help for connection between own models and the existing authorization models in `Code First`. But have nothing found what helped to me. (For example, trying [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Simple-Aspnet-Identiy-Core-7475a961)).
My exact problem:
I have a model with the entity `added_from` or `last_edited_from` and want to set a reference to the user-id. I tried it in some different ways.

The most logical way for me was:

```html
public class aTable
{
        [...]
        [ForeignKey("last_edited_from")]
        public ApplicationUser userFK { get; set; }
        public string last_edited_from { get; set; }
}
```

But when I tried this I got the following error in the Package Manager console (after "add-migration")

```html
MyProj.DAL.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
MyProj.DAL.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
```

Comment: please edit your ask and add user model

Comment: have you marked `[Key]` for identity property in your entity class, @Blacky.17?

Comment: Your error indicates that you use Identity 2.0 so for This Issue is need share your identity code for get better answer

Comment: I'll use the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity, there's no own identity code

Comment: @blacky.17 you not defind Key in User Model That inheritance of `IdentityUser<Tkey,...>`

Comment: I got the solve of my problem, the `IdentityUser` was set to the `DefaultConnection`-String. I have set it to my own Connection-String, have let my UserTable inherit from `IdentityUser` and replaced `public ApplicationUser userFK { get; set; }` with `public User userFK { get; set; }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531201/entitytype-identityuserlogin-has-no-key-defined-define-the-key-for-this-entit)

Comment: Or this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19916771/809357

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19995982/809357